# Run lengths in a binary string

Tags: distributions, combinatorics, string-count

Among the binary strings of length $n$, what is the distribution of the lengths of the homogeneous runs ?

E.g., for $n=4$ the possible strings and run lengths are

$$0000: 4;0001: 1,3;0010: 1^2,2;0011:2^2;
\\0100: 1^2,2;0101: 1^4;0110: 1^2,2;0111:1,3;
\\1000: 1,3;1001: 1^2,2;1010: 1^4;1011:1^2,2;
\\1100: 2^2;1101: 1^2,2;1110: 1,3;1111:4
$$

giving the histogram

$$1:24,\\ 2:10,\\ 3:4,\\4: 2.$$

I am also interested in the numbers of runs:

$$0000: 1;0001: 2;0010: 3;0011:2;
\\0100: 3;0101: 4;0110: 3;0111:2;
\\1000: 2;1001: 3;1010: 4;1011:3;
\\1100: 2;1101: 3;1110: 2;1111:1
$$

giving the histogram

$$1:2,\\ 2:6,\\ 3:6,\\4: 2.$$

Are there closed-form formulas ?

---

**Update:**

By shameless brute force computation I observe that the distribution of the distribution of the numbers of runs are the doubles of the Binomial numbers, and the distribution of the lengths follows the double of the sequence https://oeis.org/A045623, giving the formula

$$2\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(i+2)\binom{n-k}i.$$

Comment: Is your edit intended to answer the question? Or are you asking for proof of your brute force observation?

Comment: @Sycorax: an explanation would be fine. But if it does not come, I'll move the update to an answer in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer:**

The distribution of the numbers of runs is easily justified by induction.

Consider all sequences of $n$ bits. To obtain all sequences of $n+1$ bits, you append $0$ or $1$. This either creates a new run, or lengthens the last one. Hence,

$$C_{n+1,k}=C_{n,k-1}+C_{n,k}$$

with $$C_{1,1}=2$$

which corresponds to Pascal's triangle.